# Solving Ax=b where A is a large, banded, sparse matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, pde

I need to solve the equation `Ax = b` where `A` is a large dimensional matrix but sparse. `A` could be as large as 70000 by 70000 or even 30000 I fear!

Now `A` is also a banded matrix illustrated below. It's composed of a tridiagonal  matrix plus elements in an off diagonal above and below.

For example:

```
x x 0 0 x 0 0 

x x x 0 0 x 0

0 x x x 0 0 x

0 0 x x x 0 0

x 0 0 x x x 0

0 x 0 0 x x x

0 0 x 0 0 x x
```

Unfortunately, there's no pattern with the elements of `A` since this results from a finite difference scheme.

Any suggestions on how to solve this in MATLAB efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html#f6-9169

Comment: What's wrong with `x = b\A`? look at: [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html).

Comment: Shai, the program becomes incredibly slow with a 70000 by 70000 matrix.

Comment: @user157279 - Convert your matrices to `sparse`, then try solving it again: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html.  Also, solving for a 70000 x 70000... will obviously be naturally slow.

Comment: rayreng, I already have it in sparse format. Look, I'm doing Monte Carlo simulation so I have to repeat that 100 times for my case. and I have to do this for 12 configurations...

Comment: @user157279 Matlab linear-algebra functions are highly optimized and take into account the sparsity (http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html). If that is slow, I doubt you can make it faster

Comment: @user157279 - MATLAB's matrix inverse essentially calls BLAS and LAPACK routines under the hood and these are very very very... I mean very... highly optimized.  If the solving is slow, then there's either something wrong with the way your matrix is being formulated, or your problem is just too slow to compute a solution.

Comment: Is the matrix symmetric and positive definite?

Answer (score 0):

Try [pcg()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcg.html), which comes as standard with MATLAB.

Comment: Conjugate gradient can only be applied to certain classes of matrices.  Specifically: Symmetric and positive definite matrices.  We can't assume that the matrix the OP is creating falls under this class.

Comment: @rayryeng: If the matrix isn't positive definite then you can solve the problem A'Ax = A'b.